# Multicols & Enumitem: Can't force new page where needed

Tags: page-breaking, multicol, enumitem

The code below compiles properly with one issue:

[image]
The text instruction "**Simplify**" should be forced to the following page. I have tried `\pagebreak`, `\clearpage`, `\newpage` and `\switchcolumn*[\newpage]`.

Code line #348 is where I'm trying to force the page break:

```
{\vspace{0.5cm}}
%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
%\switchcolumn*[\newpage]
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify. }}
```

I apologize that the mwe is a bit lengthy, but I was concerned that deleting large chunks of the code would prevent the reader from being able to replicate the problem.

Thanks so much for your willingness to assist me! (Please note that I did read several page-break posts on this forum but couldn't find a solution.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Unit 13 A\&B Fractional Exponents}
       {}
       {Due 05/02/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
%\noindent 
\bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries, 
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](3)
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Change to fractional exponents.}}
% Prob #1
\task 
$\sqrt[6]{a}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{1/6}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%%%
%Prob #2
\task 
$\sqrt[4]{5}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$5^{1/4}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%%%
%Prob #3
\task 
$\sqrt[3]{x^2}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{2/3}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%%
%Prob #4
\task 
$\sqrt[4]{x^3}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/4}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%Prob #5
\task 
$\sqrt[4]{x^3y^2}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/4}y^{2/4}=x^{3/4}y^{1/2}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%%%
%Prob #6
\task 
$\sqrt[4]{x^3y^4}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/4}y^{4/4}=x^{3/4}y$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%%%
%Prob #7
\task 
$\sqrt[5]{x^3y^4z^2}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/5}y^{4/5}z^{2/5}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%%%
% Prob #8
\task 
$\sqrt[6]{a^4b^5c}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{4/6}b^{5/6}c^{1/6}$=$a^{2/3}b^{5/6}c^{1/6}$}
\end{solutionorbox}

%%%%
%%%% Prob #9
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Change to radicals.}}
\task 
$x^{3/10}$

\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[10]{x^3}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%
%%%% Prob #10
\task
$w^{4/7}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[7]{x^4}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%
%%%% Prob #11
\task
$x^{1/3}y^{2/3}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt[3]{y^2}=\sqrt[3]{xy^3}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%
%%%% Prob #12
\task
$m^{4/5}n^{3/5}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[5]{m^4}\sqrt[5]{n^3}=\sqrt[5]{m^4n^3}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%
%%%% Prob #13
\task
$(ab)^{3/4}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[4]{a^3}\sqrt[4]{b^3}=\sqrt[4]{a^3b^3}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%%% Prob #14
\task
$(bc)^{4/5}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[5]{b^4}\sqrt[5]{c^4}=\sqrt[5]{b^4c^4}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%
%%%% Prob #15
\task $(a^3b^5)^{1/6}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$(a^{3\bm{\cdot}1/6})(b^{5\bm{\cdot}1/6})$
\bigskip
$(a^{1/2})(b^{5/6})$
\bigskip
%>>>>adding \vphantom causes bot radicals to be same height
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt{\vphantom{b}a}\sqrt[6]{b^5}$  or $\sqrt[6]{a^3b^5}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%
%%%% Prob #16
\task
$(a^7b^3)^{1/8}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$(a^{7\bm{\cdot}1/8})(b^{3\bm{\cdot}1/8})$ \\
\bigskip
$(a^{7/8})(b^{3/8})$
\bigskip
%>>>>adding \vphantom causes bot radicals to be same height
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[8]{a^7b^3}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify. (Add exponents)}}
%% Prob #17
\task
$x^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}x^{1/4}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$x^{3/4+1/4}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{4/4}=x$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #18
\task
$a^{1/2}\bm{\cdot}a^{2/3}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$x^{1/2+2/3}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/6+4/6}=x^{7/6}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #19
\task
$b^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}b^{1/10}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$b^{3/4+1/10}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$b^{15/20+2/20}=x^{17/20}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #20
\task
$5^{1/4}\bm{\cdot}5^{3/4}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$5^{1/4+3/4}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$5^{4/4}=5$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #21
\task
$8^{1/3}\bm{\cdot}8^{1/4}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$8^{1/3+1/4}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$8^{4/12+3/12}=x^{7/12}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #22
\task
$z^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}z^{1/2}\bm{\cdot}z$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$z^{3/4+1/2+1}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$z^{3/4+2/4+4/4}=x^{9/4}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
{\vspace{0.5cm}}
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify (Subtract exponents)}}
%% Prob #23
\task
$\dfrac{a^{3/4}b^{1/10}}{a^{1/4}b^{1/20}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(3/4-1/4)}b^{(1/10-1/20)}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{(2/4)}b^{(1/20)}=a^{1/2}b^{1/20}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #24
\task
$\dfrac{a^{3/4}b}{a^{1/6}b^{1/3}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(3/4-1/6)}b^{(1-1/3)}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{(2/4)}b^{(1/20)}=a^{1/2}b^{1/20}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%%% Prob #25
\task
$\dfrac{a^{4/5}b^2}{a^{1/5}b^{1/2}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(4/5-1/5)}b^{(4/2-1/2)}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{3/5}b^{3/2}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%%% Prob #26
\task
$\dfrac{a^{1/2}b^2}{a^{1/4}b^{1/2}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(2/4-1/4)}b^{(4/2-1/2)}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{1/4}b^{3/2}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #27
\task
$\dfrac{a^{9/10}bc^4}{a^{1/5}b^{1/2}c^{1/2}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(9/10-2/10)}b^{(2/2-1/2)c^(8/2-1/2)}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{7/10}b^{1/2}c^{7/2)}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #28
\task
$\dfrac{a^{1.2}b^{4.8}c^{1.8}}{a^{\bm{.}8}b^2c^{1.8}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(1.2-0.8)}b^{(4.8-2.0)}c^{1.8-1.8}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{0.4}b^{2.8}c^{0}=a^{0.4}b^{2.8}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
{\vspace{0.5cm}}
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify.  (Multiply exponents)}}
%% Prob #29
\task
$(a^{1/2}b^2)\strut^{4}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(1/2 \bm{\cdot}4)}b^{(2\bm{\cdot}4)}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^2b^8$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #30
\task
$(a^{2/3}b^{1/2})\strut^{12}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(2/3\bm{\cdot}12)}b^{(1/2\bm{\cdot}12)}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^8b^6$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #31
\task
$(a^{4/5}b)\strut^{2}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(4/5\bm{\cdot}2)}b^{(1\bm{\cdot}2)}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{8/5}b^2$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #32
\task
$(a^2b^3)\strut^{1/3}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$a^{(2\bm{\cdot}1/3)}b^{(3\bm{\cdot}{1/3})}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$a^{2/3}b$}
\end{solutionorbox}
%% Prob #33
\task
$\biggl(\dfrac{a^{4/5}b^{2/3}}{c^{1/10}d^{1/3}}\biggr)^{\!20}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{a^{(4/5\bm{\cdot}20)}b^{(2/3\bm{\cdot}{20})}}{c^{(1/10\bm{\cdot}20)}d^{(1/3\bm{\cdot}20)}}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$\dfrac{a^{16}b^{40/3}}{c^2d^{20/3}}$}\
\end{solutionorbox}
{\vspace{0.5cm}}
%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
%\switchcolumn*[\newpage]
\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify. }}
%% Prob #34
\task
$\dfrac{a^{4/5}b^{2/3}}{c^{1/10}d^{1/3}}$
\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$\dfrac{a^{(4/5\bm{\cdot}20)}b^{(2/3\bm{\cdot}{20})}}{c^{(1/10\bm{\cdot}20)}d^{(1/3\bm{\cdot}20)}}$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$\dfrac{a^{16}b^{40/3}}{c^2d^{20/3}}$}\
\end{solutionorbox}
{\vspace{0.5cm}}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is the `\vspace` preceding "Simplify" in braces?  It should really be in vertical mode, ideally preceded by `\par` or a blank line, and certainly not in braces, which keep it from interacting properly with its surrounding code.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you! I commented out ```vspace``` and inserted (1)   ```\par \newpage``` and then ```\par \clearpage``` before the ```\task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify. }}``` Neither forced a new page.  Could the 3 column environment combined with horizontal enumeration be cancelling out the forced new page? Would the ```\exam``` class cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX tries to keep lists on the same page as long as there is space.

Therefore, to issue a `\clearpage` you first need `\end{tasks}`.

Then you can continue the enumeration using the `resume` key   `\begin{tasks}[resume](3)`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Unit 13 A\&B Fractional Exponents}
{}
{Due 05/02/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
    %\noindent 
    \bigskip
    \vspace{0.5mm}
}
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    %label-format = \bfseries, 
    %add \bf to make numbers bold <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fullwidth}[1]{%
    \vbox{%     
        \leftskip=-\lwidth \rightskip=0pt
        \advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin%
        \@totalleftmargin=0pt%
        #1}%
    \nobreak
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    %definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
    \def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
    \begin{tasks}
        [style=enumerate](3)
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Change to fractional exponents.}}
        % Prob #1
        \task 
        $\sqrt[6]{a}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{1/6}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%%%
        %Prob #2
        \task 
        $\sqrt[4]{5}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$5^{1/4}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%%%
        %Prob #3
        \task 
        $\sqrt[3]{x^2}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$x^{2/3}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%%
        %Prob #4
        \task 
        $\sqrt[4]{x^3}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/4}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %Prob #5
        \task 
        $\sqrt[4]{x^3y^2}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/4}y^{2/4}=x^{3/4}y^{1/2}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%%%
        %Prob #6
        \task 
        $\sqrt[4]{x^3y^4}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/4}y^{4/4}=x^{3/4}y$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%%%
        %Prob #7
        \task 
        $\sqrt[5]{x^3y^4z^2}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/5}y^{4/5}z^{2/5}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%%%
        % Prob #8
        \task 
        $\sqrt[6]{a^4b^5c}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{4/6}b^{5/6}c^{1/6}$=$a^{2/3}b^{5/6}c^{1/6}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        
        %%%%
        %%%% Prob #9
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Change to radicals.}}
        \task 
        $x^{3/10}$
        
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[10]{x^3}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%
        %%%% Prob #10
        \task
        $w^{4/7}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[7]{x^4}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%
        %%%% Prob #11
        \task
        $x^{1/3}y^{2/3}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt[3]{y^2}=\sqrt[3]{xy^3}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%
        %%%% Prob #12
        \task
        $m^{4/5}n^{3/5}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[5]{m^4}\sqrt[5]{n^3}=\sqrt[5]{m^4n^3}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%
        %%%% Prob #13
        \task
        $(ab)^{3/4}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[4]{a^3}\sqrt[4]{b^3}=\sqrt[4]{a^3b^3}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%%% Prob #14
        \task
        $(bc)^{4/5}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            \colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[5]{b^4}\sqrt[5]{c^4}=\sqrt[5]{b^4c^4}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%
        %%%% Prob #15
        \task $(a^3b^5)^{1/6}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $(a^{3\bm{\cdot}1/6})(b^{5\bm{\cdot}1/6})$
            \bigskip
            $(a^{1/2})(b^{5/6})$
            \bigskip
            %>>>>adding \vphantom causes bot radicals to be same height
            \colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt{\vphantom{b}a}\sqrt[6]{b^5}$  or $\sqrt[6]{a^3b^5}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%
        %%%% Prob #16
        \task
        $(a^7b^3)^{1/8}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $(a^{7\bm{\cdot}1/8})(b^{3\bm{\cdot}1/8})$ \\
            \bigskip
            $(a^{7/8})(b^{3/8})$
            \bigskip
            %>>>>adding \vphantom causes bot radicals to be same height
            \colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt[8]{a^7b^3}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        %%
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify. (Add exponents)}}
        %% Prob #17
        \task
        $x^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}x^{1/4}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $x^{3/4+1/4}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$x^{4/4}=x$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #18
        \task
        $a^{1/2}\bm{\cdot}a^{2/3}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $x^{1/2+2/3}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$x^{3/6+4/6}=x^{7/6}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #19
        \task
        $b^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}b^{1/10}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $b^{3/4+1/10}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$b^{15/20+2/20}=x^{17/20}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #20
        \task
        $5^{1/4}\bm{\cdot}5^{3/4}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $5^{1/4+3/4}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$5^{4/4}=5$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #21
        \task
        $8^{1/3}\bm{\cdot}8^{1/4}$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $8^{1/3+1/4}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$8^{4/12+3/12}=x^{7/12}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #22
        \task
        $z^{3/4}\bm{\cdot}z^{1/2}\bm{\cdot}z$
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $z^{3/4+1/2+1}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$z^{3/4+2/4+4/4}=x^{9/4}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        {\vspace{0.5cm}}
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify (Subtract exponents)}}
        %% Prob #23
        \task
        $\dfrac{a^{3/4}b^{1/10}}{a^{1/4}b^{1/20}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $a^{(3/4-1/4)}b^{(1/10-1/20)}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{(2/4)}b^{(1/20)}=a^{1/2}b^{1/20}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #24
        \task
        $\dfrac{a^{3/4}b}{a^{1/6}b^{1/3}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $a^{(3/4-1/6)}b^{(1-1/3)}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{(2/4)}b^{(1/20)}=a^{1/2}b^{1/20}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %%% Prob #25
        \task
        $\dfrac{a^{4/5}b^2}{a^{1/5}b^{1/2}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $a^{(4/5-1/5)}b^{(4/2-1/2)}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{3/5}b^{3/2}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %%% Prob #26
        \task
        $\dfrac{a^{1/2}b^2}{a^{1/4}b^{1/2}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $a^{(2/4-1/4)}b^{(4/2-1/2)}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{1/4}b^{3/2}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #27
        \task
        $\dfrac{a^{9/10}bc^4}{a^{1/5}b^{1/2}c^{1/2}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $a^{(9/10-2/10)}b^{(2/2-1/2)}c^{(8/2-1/2)}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{7/10}b^{1/2}c^{7/2)}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #28
        \task
        $\dfrac{a^{1.2}b^{4.8}c^{1.8}}{a^{\bm{.}8}b^2c^{1.8}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $a^{(1.2-0.8)}b^{(4.8-2.0)}c^{1.8-1.8}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{0.4}b^{2.8}c^{0}=a^{0.4}b^{2.8}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify.  (Multiply exponents)}}
        %% Prob #29
        \task
        $(a^{1/2}b^2)\strut^{4}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $a^{(1/2 \bm{\cdot}4)}b^{(2\bm{\cdot}4)}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^2b^8$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #30
        \task
        $(a^{2/3}b^{1/2})\strut^{12}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $a^{(2/3\bm{\cdot}12)}b^{(1/2\bm{\cdot}12)}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^8b^6$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #31
        \task
        $(a^{4/5}b)\strut^{2}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $a^{(4/5\bm{\cdot}2)}b^{(1\bm{\cdot}2)}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{8/5}b^2$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #32
        \task
        $(a^2b^3)\strut^{1/3}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $a^{(2\bm{\cdot}1/3)}b^{(3\bm{\cdot}{1/3})}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$a^{2/3}b$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        %% Prob #33
        \task
        $\biggl(\dfrac{a^{4/5}b^{2/3}}{c^{1/10}d^{1/3}}\biggr)^{\!20}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $\dfrac{a^{(4/5\bm{\cdot}20)}b^{(2/3\bm{\cdot}{20})}}{c^{(1/10\bm{\cdot}20)}d^{(1/3\bm{\cdot}20)}}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$\dfrac{a^{16}b^{40/3}}{c^2d^{20/3}}$}\
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        %********************************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \end{tasks} 
        \clearpage      
        \begin{tasks}[resume](3)
        %************************************************************   
        \task![]\fullwidth{\textbf{Simplify. }} 
        %% Prob #34
        \task
        $\dfrac{a^{4/5}b^{2/3}}{c^{1/10}d^{1/3}}$
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
            $\dfrac{a^{(4/5\bm{\cdot}20)}b^{(2/3\bm{\cdot}{20})}}{c^{(1/10\bm{\cdot}20)}d^{(1/3\bm{\cdot}20)}}$
            \bigskip
            \colorbox{yellow}{$\dfrac{a^{16}b^{40/3}}{c^2d^{20/3}}$}\
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To my rescue again! I figured that ```\tasks``` was the culprit in terms of negating the forcing of a page break. But just couldn't figure out how to turn it off! Your explanation is most helpful and far more efficient than guessing & checking which value of ```vspace``` will force new page without also pushing extra listed items to next page. Thanks very much!